# Laravel database, what data type should I use to store email?

Tags: php, laravel, database, model, migration

```
Schema::create('signups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('first name');

            $table->string('last name');

            $table->??('email');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Use `string()` too

Comment: If you're wondering if there's any specialized data type that is intended to be used just for emails, there is none such type in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use string as follows:

```
$table->string('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use string type like this:

```
$table->string('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below codes, both are correct:

```
$table->string('email')
$table->varchar('email')
```